# How to show location in Sublime Text file preview (right sidebar)?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When you open a file in sublime text it shows a small version of it on the right side where you can click and scroll. In sublime text 2 it always stayed highlighted on where you are in the file, but in 3 it no longer does. I am wondering how to get this feature back, and also what the correct name for this right side bar preview thing is.

This is what it looks like in 3

[image: This is what it looks like in 3]

This is what it looks like in 2 and what I am going for. Notice how the top of the right side-bar is highlighted a lighter gray.

[image]

Comment: I think they made those modifications in newer versions of Sublime Text. May be for giving more UX

Comment: That is called the minimap. I don't use 3 and 2 doesn't seem to have any options for it other than hide and show.  Maybe 3 has some options for it.  Or maybe you can use the console to set options.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add this line to your user settings:

```
"always_show_minimap_viewport": true
```

Thanks @Rico for telling me it is called a minimap !!

Comment: additionally, if you want a border around the viewport, use `"draw_minimap_border": true`